# Implement andmap function in scheme for any number of lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I got a question to implement the **andmap** scheme function - [andmap proc](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29).

The output seposed to be:

[image]

Now, I have a code for andmap func but it is not good for more that one list.

my code:

```
(define (andmap1 pred lox)
(foldr (lambda (x y) (and x y)) true (map pred lox)))
```

my output:
[image]

can someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a conceptual problem with the way you're attempting to implement `andmap`. It's supposed to be short-circuit evaluation, that means it must stop as soon as a `false` value is found, and the return value is the result of evaluating the last expression in the input.

That's why the `(map pred lox)` part will fail with the `(andmap1 positive? '(1 -2 a))` example as soon as the `a` is reached, and anyway `foldr` will try to consume the whole input list - we don't want either of those things to happen.

With the above considerations in mind, plus the requirement of operating over multiple input lists, the solution changes quite a bit:

```
(define (andmap1 pred . lox) ; lox is a variable-length list of lists
  (let loop ((lst lox)) ; iterate using a named `let`
    (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? (car lst))) ; if the input is empty
           true) ; then the result is `true`
          ((null? (cdar lst)) ; if there's a single element left in sublists
           (apply pred (map car lst))) ; return pred applied to all
          ((not (apply pred (map car lst))) ; if current elements fail pred
           false) ; short-circuit and return `false` immediately
          (else (loop (map cdr lst)))))) ; advance recursion on all sublists
```

It works as expected:

```
(andmap1 positive? '(1 2 3))
=> #t

(andmap1 positive? '(1 2 a))
=> positive?: contract violation expected: real? given: 'a

(andmap1 positive? '(1 -2 a))
=> #f

(andmap1 + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can write it, but note it doesn't have an early-exit behavior because `foldl` is used. As we can see, the implementation is made up of a combination of `map` and a folding of `and` -

```
(define (andmap f . ls)
  (foldl (lambda (x acc) (and acc x))
         #t
         (apply map
                (lambda xs (apply f xs))
                ls)))

(andmap positive? '(1 2 3)) ; #t

(andmap + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) ; 9
```